# Using custom files in Ruby/scripts to create working wc3 map

Tags: ruby, argv

I am totally green in those kind of things, I tried reading some tutorials and still couldn't do it on my own.
Here lies the problem: I have 2 files (bulid, compile) which are somehow supposed to take other files and create a working warcraft3 map.
There's an instruction I followed:

**To build:_**

```
$ ./scripts/compile  # most basic way of calling compile
$ ./scripts/build    # most basic way of building a map
```

### build

Script which takes an unportected map and applies any build settings passed via argv
upon on it then turns it into a working warcraft3 map file.

Options         | Default                 | Description
----------------|-------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------
env             | beta                    | map environment: each environment has default build settings
debug_script    | false                   | debug this build script
do_jasshelper   | true                    | turns vJass & ZINC into JASS
do_compile      | true                    | turns ../src into out.j. When false, looks for {map_script_path}
do_optimizer    | false                   | uses Vexorian's map optimizer to protect and make the map run faser
do_widgetizer   | false                   | uses PitzerMike's map widgetizer to make map load faster
debug           | false                   | whether the --debug flag should be passed to jasshelper
launchwc3       | false                   | whether the script should launch wc3 with the map loaded on exit
map_unpro_path  | base-maps/{highest}.w3x | the base map file to inject script into
map_script_path | ../out.j                | map script path to load into map
map_output_path | ITT_{commit}_{time}.w3x | path where to put the compiled map

### setting up

This application requires Ruby

```
$ git clone git@github.com:theQuazz/island-troll-tribes
$ cd island-troll-tribes
$ scripts/build
```

It might be a easy thing to do, but I am really bad at this kind of stuff, if someone could explain what to do step by step I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Silly question, do you have ruby installed on your machine?

Comment: Along with @hraynaud's question, What OS are you using and is it of 32-bit  ? Do you have Git installed or have you downloaded the source as zip from Github ?

Comment: I have win8 64bit, downloaded source from github. There's the orginal instruction with new addition: https://github.com/theQuazz/island-troll-tribes maybe it can help.

Comment: And yes I have ruby installed, btw author added new instructions which seem to be much more clear. I linked the site in the last post.